# Return Only Number from string in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have query which returns **ILS 400,000.00**, but i want it as **400000** only, pls advice.
thanks

Comment: Victim of a bad db design...

Comment: column doesn't has fixed data pattern.

Comment: What do you need in case of `'1 abc 123.45'` or `'1 2 ab3c 123.45 2'`, ... ? please post more informations on the logics you need and/or more sample data and desired result

Comment: Is the ILS a currency, and if so is the string you have always representing Israeli new shekels?

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex functions in the oracle database. The replace function was introduced in the Database [Version 10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
-- \D does replace every non digit char
select regexp_replace('ILS 400,000.00', '\D*(\d+)[,.](\d+).*', '\1\2') 
-- replace with capturing groups 1 and 2, which should be 400 and 000 in this example
from dual;
```

Comment: This does not respect positions after decimal point. Anyway, the requirement is not totally clear as already commented above...

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss yeah, you are right. Changed so it does also remove the decimal places.